# Port from which requests originate + HTTP

Tags: http, servlets

I have a web application running on port 8080 of a server. I am accessing this application from my windows machine. From which port on my windows machine does the request originate? How does the server send back the response to the same port? Is it all handled by HTTP specification?

Answer (score 1):

It's handled by [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), which is the underlying transport protocol used by HTTP.  When a client connects to a server using TCP, it sets up a client port and includes it in the TCP header of every packet it sends to the server.  The server knows which port to send the response to based on seeing this in the header.

Comment: Thanks a lot Don! Is this port arbitrarily chosen when a HTTP request is sent or is there a specific port from which HTTP request always originate?